# golang xml parsing dynamic tag names

Tags: xml, go, xml-parsing

I must parse the xml output of an legacy system where they for some reason thought that it will be smart to add the IDs of values as tag names.

Like so:

```
<ValueList>
  <ArraySize>2</ArraySize>
  <v89BNZMpdlWXkuv>value1</v89BNZMpdlWXkuv>
  <v89N83oCrGhI7jh>value2</v89N83oCrGhI7jh>
</ValueList>
```

I want to parse it to a struct like this:

```
type ValueList struct {
    Values []Value
}

type Value struct {
    ID string
    Value String
}
```

I've started using the custom unmarshal function

```
func (vl *ValueList) UnmarshalXML(d *xml.Decoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    ...
}
```

and getting the tokens from the `xml.Decoder`, but that is ugly. Is there a better way?

Comment: Did you try `xml:",any"`?

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/7rapNXzvJgZ

Comment: this is the answer! I didn't know about `xml:",any"` and played with this problem for too long :/ thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to store it in a struct, you can refer this:

[Dynamic Xml Processing](https://github.com/vikasgowda3007/golang/tree/master/dynamicXmlProcessing/core)

It basically taken in a XML and returns a map, with key being the tag name and value being the tag value.

In your case the resulting map will be:

```
{
"ValueList>ArraySize":"2",
"ValueList>v89BNZMpdlWXkuv":"value1",
"ValueList>v89N83oCrGhI7jh":"value2"
}
```

Separator of key can be sent as a parameter. Here symbol ">" is the separator which is sent as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can used [xmlquery](https://github.com/antchfx/xmlquery) to parse XML and extract data, even it's dynamic tag name. code like this:

```
doc,err:=xmlquery.Parse(`<xml>..`)
node:=xmlquery.FindOne(doc,"//ValueList")
// Travel all child-node of ValueList
for n:=node.FirstChild;n!=nil;n=n.NextSibling{
  fmt.Println(n.Data) // Ouptut name: ArraySize,v89BNZMpdlWXkuv,v89N83oCrGhI7jh
  fmt.Println(n.InnerText())// Value of child-node.
}
```

Hope can help you.